# Video.js and 404 console error: Why the error despite having file on server?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, google-chrome-devtools, video.js

I'm trying to get a background video to work on my [**sandbox site here**](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/) but for some reason I'm getting a "404 Not Found" on the video.js file that is supposed to enable background videos. However, I do see the video.js file when I click on the line# in console. So, why am I seeing a 404 in console? I suspect this is the reason I am not able to view background videos, but not sure how to fix. Thanks for any clues anyone can provide!

Comment: OK, if I used a CDN it worked, but if I didn't, I'd get the 404 error.

Comment: Your sandbox example is working for me. No 404 except for some unrelated image file. "http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/images/customers2.png"